# XSLT group by attribute entries from list

Tags: php, xslt

I have a problem getting the right XSLT together to create a group of elements based on the value of an attribute. This is my XML:

```
<companies>
  <country iso="DE">
    <item name="Strawberry Raw Pressed Juice" company="Snack Inc." />
    <item name="Apple Raw Pressed Juice" company="Max Food Ltd." />
    <item name="Sweet Apple Raw Pressed Juice" company="Snack Inc." />
  </country>
  <country iso="SE">
    <item name="Sweet Mixed Pickles" company="Snack Inc." />
    <item name="Apple Raw Pressed Juice" company="Baked Beans A/S" />
    <item name="Leisure Luv Apples" company="Snack Inc." />
  </country>
</companies>
```

I want to extend the country list and insert a company entry inside once per company containing the items of that company.

I have a basic XSLT setup already running and the country list working. I started with a for-each to go over the items per country (country is a template), so that is within the country template.

If I now for-each over the items, I get all items. But I would like to have a list of the unique company names first, so therefore group the items inside there.

Should I do two transformations maybe? First grouping items into duplicate company nodes and then in a second transformation putting them into one field?

Comment: Could you post the expected result?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for the only solution that uses Muenchian grouping on a composite, two part key.

Comment: Yeah I'm studying the answers right now. I started with empo's which doesn't use that Muenchian grouping and it is too slow. I've read about [muenchian grouping now](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) which looks fine to deal with the speed/adds the indexing. And I've seen your composite key which is great because for my RL data I'm actually pretty sure I need it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kItemByCompCountry" match="item"
  use="concat(../@iso,'+++',@company)"/>

 <xsl:template match="*[not(self::item)]">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "item[generate-id()
       =
        generate-id(key('kItemByCompCountry',
                        concat(../@iso,
                              '+++',@company)
                        )[1]
                    )
       ]
  ">
  <company name="{@company}">
   <xsl:copy-of select=
   "key('kItemByCompCountry',
        concat(../@iso,'+++',@company))"/>
  </company>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<companies>
    <country iso="DE">
        <item name="Strawberry Raw Pressed Juice" company="Snack Inc." />
        <item name="Apple Raw Pressed Juice" company="Max Food Ltd." />
        <item name="Sweet Apple Raw Pressed Juice" company="Snack Inc." />
    </country>
    <country iso="SE">
        <item name="Sweet Mixed Pickles" company="Snack Inc." />
        <item name="Apple Raw Pressed Juice" company="Baked Beans A/S" />
        <item name="Leisure Luv Apples" company="Snack Inc." />
    </country>
</companies>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<companies>
  <country iso="DE">
    <company name="Snack Inc.">
      <item name="Strawberry Raw Pressed Juice" company="Snack Inc." />
      <item name="Sweet Apple Raw Pressed Juice" company="Snack Inc." />
    </company>
    <company name="Max Food Ltd.">
      <item name="Apple Raw Pressed Juice" company="Max Food Ltd." />
    </company>
  </country>
  <country iso="SE">
    <company name="Snack Inc.">
      <item name="Sweet Mixed Pickles" company="Snack Inc." />
      <item name="Leisure Luv Apples" company="Snack Inc." />
    </company>
    <company name="Baked Beans A/S">
      <item name="Apple Raw Pressed Juice" company="Baked Beans A/S" />
    </company>
  </country>
</companies>
```

Comment: I'll try to adopt this. PHP XSLTProcessor warns me that version 2.0 is not supported and it degrades to 1.0, but maybe it works. I'll test.

Comment: @hakre: The 2.0 isn't necessary -- it is my copy/paste error -- please, ignore it completely and use 1.0. I am fixing this in my answer.

Comment: I can get it to work on my test-data but I fail on the live data. However this seems to work. I only wonder why those `xmlns` are added per company.

Comment: I could fix the `xmlns` issue by using `<xsl:element name="company">` so the output is a little smaller. It now works as well on my live-data (had missed to make a renaming). Like a breeze even for larger files. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @hakre: Again my copy/paste mistake: the namespace definition for XML Schema is not necessary and can be removed -- I'm fixing my answer now -- sorry, but I'm a little bit sleepy, especially early Monday morning... :)

Comment: Okay, I see the difference in code, and it works for me. One day even I will get a decent knowledge of the namespace details ;)

Comment: @Dimitre: Do you think the degree of performances caused in my answer is really due to `preceding-sibling` or may be to what else? +1 for absolutely perfect answer ever :)).

Comment: @empo: The preceding-sibling::name solution is really slow -- O(N^2). THis qadratical time complexity may be minor for short sequences of nodes but it becomes prohibitive as N (the average number of nodes to be deduped) grows. If N is increased 10 times, such solution will need 100 times more time to process this.

Comment: @Dimitre: could not have better explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Like this?:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:key name="company" match="item" use="@company" />

   <xsl:template match="companies">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:for-each select="country/item[generate-id() = generate-id(key('company',@company)[1])]">
         <xsl:variable name="company" select="@company" />
         <company name="{$company}">
           <xsl:apply-templates select="../../country/item[@company = $company]" />
         </company>
       </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="item">
     <item name="{@name}" country="{../@iso}" />
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This uses the Muenchian grouping method to group by company. Google for it if you need to know more.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! And you made me google that Muenchian method :) This method gives me the speed I need, nice one!

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:key name="groupCompanies" match="item" use="@company" />

<xsl:template match="companies">

  <xsl:for-each select="//item[generate-id() = generate-id( key('groupCompanies', @company)) [1] ) ]">
    <xsl:sort select="@company" order="ascending" />
    <xsl:call-template name="group">
        <xsl:with-param name="ck" select="@company" />
      </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="group">
  <xsl:param name="ck" /> 

  <xsl:for-each select="//item[@company = $ck]">
     ....
  </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not "for-each" at all, you don't need it to. You can do grouping directly from the `country` element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="country">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="item[
                 preceding-sibling::item/@company!=@company]" 
                 mode="group"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="item" mode="group">
            <company name="{@company}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="../item[
                        @company=current()/@company]"/>
            </company>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="item">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This transform produces:

```
<companies>
   <country iso="DE">
      <company name="Max Food Ltd.">
         <item name="Apple Raw Pressed Juice" company="Max Food Ltd."/>
      </company>
      <company name="Snack Inc.">
         <item name="Strawberry Raw Pressed Juice" company="Snack Inc."/>
         <item name="Sweet Apple Raw Pressed Juice" company="Snack Inc."/>
      </company>
   </country>
   <country iso="SE">
      <company name="Baked Beans A/S">
         <item name="Apple Raw Pressed Juice" company="Baked Beans A/S"/>
      </company>
      <company name="Snack Inc.">
         <item name="Sweet Mixed Pickles" company="Snack Inc."/>
         <item name="Leisure Luv Apples" company="Snack Inc."/>
      </company>
   </country>
</companies>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I started with your answer but then ran into speed problems for my large amount of data. The `preceding-sibling::item` was causing that, so I skipped over to one of the other answers. But thanks a lot for your suggestion. I learned that I can re-use the templates, I was not aware of that earlier.

Comment: You are welcome. You are true. This method is really instructive as first approach to grouping, however has the disadvantage of slowing performances when applied on huge input trees.

Comment: Yeah I have some 16.000 items in the one file, the other is even larger.